# Renderizar campo JSON Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates, django3

Estou fazendo um projeto usando o Django 3.1.2, este projeto precisa de um registro de logs.

Eu criei um modelo para logs:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    Usuario = models.CharField('Usuário que fez a ação', max_length=100)
    Perfil = models.SmallIntegerField('Quem está sofrendo a ação', choices=PERFIL_CHOICE)
    Acao = models.CharField('Tipo de Ação Realizada', max_length=2, choices=ACAO_CHOICE)
    Resultado = models.JSONField('Resultado', null=True, blank=True)
    Processando = models.BooleanField('Processando', default=True)
    TituloProcesso = models.CharField("Titulo do Processo", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    DataAcao = models.DateTimeField('Data da Ação', auto_now_add=True)
```

O log do modelo possui o campo "Resultado" que é do tipo JSONField, este campo está funcionando corretamente.

Os dados que são salvos no campo são dinâmicos, então as chaves e valores json não serão sempre os mesmos, então é necessário mais fácil exibir este campo no modelo.

Estava procurando o "django-jsonfiel", não funciona no Django 3.1

Alguém conhece alguma forma de exibir este campo já formatado dinamicamente?

Comment: O que você chama de exibir? Algo como `print(json.dumps(SEU_JSON, indent=4, sort_keys=True))` ajuda?

Comment: Boa tarde, isso seria uma solução sim so que eu tentei jogar no template, colocando essa formatação em uma variavel so que no template não fica igual no print do terminal, não pega a formatação.

Comment: Tenta passar o `json.dumps(SEU_JSON, indent=4)` para o template e mostre lá com `{{ VARIAVEL_JSON | linebreaks }}`

Comment: Opa bom dia, muito obrigado @PauloMarques deu certo, queria saber se tem alguma tag pra as identações e se você tem algum link com essas tags para que eu possa da uma estudada nelas .

Comment: Veja a documentação do DJango [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/)

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado Paulo a quebra de linha com o "linebreaks" funcionou.

To com uma outra duvida aqui que não consigo resolver que e codificar o json pro utf-8.

no terminal ele exibi normao codificado template não, já tentei codificar antes depois, até consegui codificar so que ai ele perde a formatação.

tentei dessa forma mais não vai:

```
@login_required
```

def log_detail_view(request, log_id):
objLog = Log.objects.get(pk=log_id)
print(objLog.Resultado)
data = str(objLog.Resultado).encode('utf-8')
data = data.decode('utf-8')

```
resultado = json.dumps(objLog.Resultado, indent=4)
print(resultado)
data = str(resultado).encode('utf-8')
data = data.decode('utf-8')
# print(data)
context = {
    'user': request.user,
    'objLog': objLog,
    'resultado': resultado,
}
return render(request, "relatorio/log_detail.html", context)
```

se alguém souber.

Comment: Outra dúvida outro post. Não faça dos posts sala de bate-papo